# Probability to meet SLA based on deliverability

Tags: probability, statistics

It's been about 15 years since I had a probability or stats class, so I'm asking this here.

- I have an event that runs every hour.
- There is a 1/100 (1%) chance that the event fails at any time.
- What is the probability that the feed fails 14 or more times in any 14 rolling day period?

Comment: A feed like a signal? Does it come back on once it fails? I think you need to better define the criteria of the problem.

Comment: @stuartstevenson I've changed the wording to "event" -- i.e., like a 100-sided die that is rolled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fails are independent then the binomial distribution can be used.  $P=\sum_{k=m}^N\binom{N}{k}p^k(1-p)^{N-k}$  where $N=336$ is the total number of events,  $m=14$ minimum number of fails for this calculation, and $p=.01$, the probability of one failure.

Comment: thanks for this. What does the actual answer come out to then?

Comment: I have not made the calculation.  If you wish, $1-P$ is easy to get, since it has only 14 terms.  Let $T_k=\binom{N}{k}p^k(1-p)^{N-k}$  The calculation of $1-P=\sum_{k=0}^{13}T_k$ is relatively straightforward.  Start with $T_0=(1-p)^N$ and use the fact that $\frac{T_{k+1}}{T_k}=\frac{N-k}{k+1}\frac{p}{1-p}$